# Comparing two lists of tuples and looking for different values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists of tuples. For example:

The first one I keep:

```
[
("base", "first_val", "value 1", "1"),
("base", "first_val", "value 2", "0"),
("base", "first_val", "value 3", "2"),
("base", "second_val", "value 1", "10"),
("base", "second_val", "value 2", "10"),
("base", "third_val", "value 1", "100"),
("base", "third_val", "value 2", "1"),
("base", "fourth_val", "value 1", "param 1", "22"),
("base", "fourth_val", "value 2", "param 1", "222"),
("base", "fourth_val", "value 3", "12")
]
```

10 tuples, 4 parameters with subparameters.

The second one I get. This list may have other content:

```
[
("base", "first_val", "value 1", "10000"),              #changed
("base", "first_val", "value 2", "5555"),               #changed
("base", "first_val", "value 3", "2"),                  #not changed
("base", "fourth_val", "value 1", "param 1", "22"),     #not changed
("base", "fourth_val", "value 2", "param 1", "100000"), #changed
("base", "fourth_val", "value 3", "12")                 #not changed
]
```

6 tuples, 2 parameters with subparameters.

In fact, these are sheets with hundreds of entries.

The filling of the resulting list with tuples is constantly changing, but the general principle of constructing tuples is preserved. How to get only those tuples that have changed in the fastest possible way?

Comment: Store it as a `dict` where the first three values from the `tuple` are the key, the last one is the value?

Comment: Use a set of you don't care about order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set` in Python to determine changed values:

```py
first_list = [("base", "first_val", "value 1", "1"),
              ("base", "first_val", "value 2", "0"),
              ("base", "first_val", "value 3", "2"),
              ("base", "second_val", "value 1", "10"),
              ("base", "second_val", "value 2", "10"),
              ("base", "third_val", "value 1", "100"),
              ("base", "third_val", "value 2", "1"),
              ("base", "fourth_val", "value 1", "param 1", "22"),
              ("base", "fourth_val", "value 2", "param 1", "222"),
              ("base", "fourth_val", "value 3", "12")]

second_list = [
    ("base", "first_val", "value 1", "10000"),  #changed
    ("base", "first_val", "value 2", "5555"),  #changed
    ("base", "first_val", "value 3", "2"),  #not changed
    ("base", "fourth_val", "value 1", "param 1", "22"),  #not changed
    ("base", "fourth_val", "value 2", "param 1", "100000"),  #changed
    ("base", "fourth_val", "value 3", "12")  #not changed
]

changed = list(set(second_list) - set(first_list))
print(changed)
```

This outputs:

```py
[('base', 'fourth_val', 'value 2', 'param 1', '100000'),
 ('base', 'first_val', 'value 1', '10000'),
 ('base', 'first_val', 'value 2', '5555')]
```

[Repl Link](https://replit.com/@LukeStorry/72200238#main.py)